# Showing that $\forall a\in \mathbb Z \exists b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ab+1$ is perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

first time asking a question here.

This proof seems simple, but the only part throwing me off is the the first two remarks
"Show that for every positive integer a, there exist a positive integer $b$ such that $ab+1$ is a perfect square."

What I have is: 
Let $k = n^2$ where is an integer and $n^2$ is perfect square.
then $ab+ 1 = k $

This is where I get stuck.

Comment: **Hint:** Expand $(a+1)^2$.

Comment: This is a mere  translation into formula of what has to be proved. What stucks you?

Comment: the quantifiers is what throws me off. If the quantifiers weren't there then  I would do a straight algebraic proof.

Comment: The quantifies say $a$ is given.  You can find $b$ and $n$. You are kind of working backwords by starting with the $n^2$.  If you start with $ab + 1 = n^2$ you need to work backwords and solve for $b$ in terms of $a$.  $ab + 1 = n^2$ then $b = (n^2 - 1)/a = (n+1)(n-1)/a$.  We need to argue that we can find $n$ where that works.  Obviously we can let $n-1 = k*a$ or $n = k*a - 1$ and $b= k(ka-1)$.  So for all $a$ then $a*(k(ka-1))+1=(ka-1)^2$

Comment: You do not need $n$ or $k$. You are looking for a good $b$ depending on $a$. If you try this, certainly $b=a+2$ comes to mind. Then $ab+1=a(a+2)+1=(a+1)^2$ is a square.

Comment: $$\forall n \in \mathbb{W}, \ \sum_{i = 0}^{n}8i + 1 = m^2$$ $$(\nexists ab \in \mathbb{R}) \left[ab = m\right] \iff \forall k \in \mathbb{W}, \ n = 2k + 1$$ That is to say, if $m$ is prime, $n$ must be odd, however this does not cover *all* integers for $m$. And if you do not know, $\mathbb{W} = \{0, 1, 2,\ldots\} =$ the set of *Whole Numbers*.

Answer (score 2):

$$a*b+1=n^2$$
$$a*b=n^2-1$$
$$a*b=(n-1)*(n+1)$$
From there, let $a$ or $b$ equal one of the two terms on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

If you set $b=a+2$, then $ab+1=a(a+2)+1=a^2+2a+1=(a+1)^2$, as per Henning's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The quantifiers say that $a$ is fixed and that you need to find *some* $b$ and $n$ in terms of $a$.

So if we want $ab + 1 = n^2$ we want $b = \frac{n^2 -1}a$ and $n = \pm\sqrt{ab+1}$.

The latter doesn't suggest any thing but $b = \frac{n^2 -1}a = \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}a$

So all we have to do is pick *any* $n$ so that $a|n\pm 1$.  Why not simply $n = a-1$?

If $n = a - 1$ then $b =  \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}a= \frac {(a-2)a}a = a-2$

So for every $a$ we can always find $b = a-2$ and $n = a-1$ so  $ab + 1 = a(a-2) + 1 = a^2 - 2a +1 = (a-1)^2 = n^2$.  Always.  For all $a$.

These aren't the only ones.  We could have found $n= ak\pm1$ and $b = k(ka \pm 2)$ so $ab + 1 = ak(ka \pm 2) = a^2k^2 \pm 2ak + 1 = (ak \pm 1)^2 = n^2$ for any $k$.